# Intellij install under sudo command

Tags: intellij

recently I installed IntelliJ Ultimate under linux with command `sudo ./idea.sh`, and it somehow installed somewhere in my roots of linux.
When i run just `./idea.sh` to install, it installs under my user and everything is fine.
Question is: 
Where I can find those folders unders roots to delete config files, because i want to delete it completely from roots. I searched a lot, but did not find anything.

Comment: Oops! Try looking in `/opt/intellij`...

Answer (score 1):

You should delete these two directories:

```
/root/.IdeaIC2017.1/
/root/IdeaProjects
```

Note that you will need to open it from the terminal as root or use your file manager with root privileges (for example, run `sudo -i`) since non-root users can't access that directory.

Comment: Yes , tried this yesterday.

Comment: " By default, IntelliJ IDEA stores all your settings under the ~/.IdeaIC2017.1/config
  directory and uses ~/.IdeaIC2017.1/system as a data cache."   Right from IntelliJ's README

Comment: I don't see why not, running it with `sudo` is basically running it with the root account. Beside that, I have tried it and It turned to be it in my case.

Comment: the script might contain instructions about what to do if the `$EUID` is 0. `/root` is a pretty dumb place to install any executable. But I have seen enough crappy installation scripts to believe that it's possible...

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the `idea.sh` script and see where it installs what.

Then you can revert that installation manually.

Comment: I read that file several times, but didn't find anything.
Problem is, that when I sudo, it loads configuration file from somewhere in root, but I can't find it. The thing is what I want to do: Find that rooted configuration file, and delete it, so I could fresh sudo ./idea.sh and enter my all credentials again, like from fresh start.

Comment: You have already trusted `idea.sh` too much, so this will probably not do more system damage. First, type `script idealog.log`, then `sudo bash -x ./idea.sh`, then when it completes, `exit`.  The file `idealog.log` will provide interesting reading.